# Avoid removal of a file on plugin update

Tags: updates

When I update a plugin, all the files are completely wiped.

Is it possible, by any means, to avoid the removal of one very specific file within the plugin folder during the update?

I've noticed that the WP Update process wipes the plugin folder before reinstalling the new files, so I feel that this will be unlikely to be possible... but maybe there is something that may enable this.

Comment: Can you offer more context?  Like, are you adding a file to a plugin that isn't yours?  That's not a best practice specifically for reasons such as this.

Comment: What does this file do? You should be using hooks/actions and filters to modify plugin behaviour, not direct edits to plugin files